# Sql show top 10 requested products of every group

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have the following data stored in my database.

I want to know what the 10 most searched parts are for every car.
Below I made an example of the data that is stored in the database.

One table contains the names of the cars with the car id.
One table contains the requests with one or more request id('s) for every car.
One table contains the request id with the name of the requested part.

```
Table cars

audi        (7)
bmw         (12)

Table request
7           (100)
7           (234)
7           (367)
7           (562)
7           (729)
7           (765)
7           (881)

Table request_parts

100         (achterband)
234         (voorband)
367         (motor)
562         (accu)
729         (achterband)
765         (kopeling)
881         (koeling)
```

What the query should return is something like this, as in the example 'achterband' was found twice

```
audi        achterband      2
audi        voorband        1
audi        motor           1
audi        accu            1
audi        kopeling        1
```

The query that I currently have counts how often the part 'motor' has been requested for every car. however I can't find out how to do this not just for one product but for all of them at the same time. right now its not important to have the name of the car as the id is already shown.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), requests.sibben_brand_id, request_parts.name
FROM request_parts
JOIN requests ON requests.id = request_parts.request_id
WHERE requests.sibben_brand_id IS NOT NULL 
AND request_parts.name LIKE  'motor'
GROUP BY requests.sibben_brand_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC `
```

Does any one has a idea how i could get the correct data?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: kopeling wasn't found twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), requests.sibben_brand_id, request_parts.name
FROM request_parts
JOIN requests ON requests.id = request_parts.request_id
WHERE requests.sibben_brand_id IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY requests.sibben_brand_id,request_parts.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC `
```

Answer (score 0):

with

```
cars table as (id,name)
request table as (id,car_id,request_id)
request_parts table as (id,request_id,part_name)`
```

the following query returns top 10 records

```
select top 10 c.name, rqp.part_name,count(*) as repetition
from request as r, request_parts as rqp, cars as c
where rqp.request_id = r.request_id AND r.car_id = c.Id
group by rqp.part_name,c.name
order by repetition desc`
```